# Error when trying to retrieve data from Windows Azure Mobile Services Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to retrieve data from azure mobile services using this query. However it's not working and I am sure their is data in the database.

```
userTable.where().field("id").eq(1).execute(new TableQueryCallback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<User> users, int i, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse) {
```

This is how I initialized the MobileServiceClient.

```
 try
    {

        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(getString(R.string.azure_site),getString(R.string.azure_key),this);
        mClient.setGsonBuilder(new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES));
        mClient.registerSerializer(ArrayList.class,new CollectionSerializer<Object>());
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        AppMsg.makeText(this, getString(R.string.service_error), AppMsg.STYLE_ALERT).show();
    }
```

This is my User model.

```
public class User
{

private int id;
private String facebookId;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private ArrayList<Alarm> alarms;
private ArrayList<Moment> moments;
private ArrayList<User> bannedUsers;
private String channel;


public String getRegistrationId() {
    return channel;
}


public final void setRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
    channel = registrationId;
}



public User()
{

}

public User(int userId,String facebookId,String firstname,String  lastname,ArrayList<Alarm> alarms,ArrayList<Moment> moments,ArrayList<User> bannedUsers)
{
    //this.moments = moments;
    this.alarms = alarms;
    this.id = userId;
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
   this.bannedUsers = bannedUsers;
}
/**
 * Getters and setters
 *
 */
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public final void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public final  void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public final void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof User && ((User) o).id == id;
}

public String getFacebookId() {
    return facebookId;
}

public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
}

public ArrayList<Alarm> getAlarms() {
    return alarms;
}

public void setAlarms(ArrayList<Alarm> alarms) {
    this.alarms= alarms;
}

public ArrayList<Moment> getMoments() {
    return moments;
}

public void setHistory(ArrayList<Moment> moments) {
    this.moments = moments;
}

public ArrayList<User> getBannedUsers() {
    return bannedUsers;
}

public void setBannedUsers(ArrayList<User> bannedUsers) {
    this.bannedUsers = bannedUsers;
}

}
```

Data is present inside the database.(This is test data.)

[image]

I am really not sure about what's causing the problem. I am not getting an error message, just a null when I receive the array in the onComplete callback.

Things to point out.

- I am using a custom collection serializer/deserializer and I am sure its working, I tested it.
- I have internet access on my Android phone.
- The mobile client is being initialized because I tried retrieving data from another table and it works.
- I dont need annotations because I am telling GSON to automatically generate them for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the table and recreating it? Something could have gone wrong causing the table to not function properly when being read from.